# How to view my Excel sheet normally without grouping but keep the grouping configuration?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel we can group rows by going to `Menu - Data - Group - select Group by Rows` for the selected cells e.g. one [demo here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0V4G7H2u538).

After we do that, the left column changed as below snapshot where we have grouping control on the side.

I need to keep the grouping cells in group and sometimes like to view my sheet as normal view without grouping.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: It would help to know why you want to hide the grouping tool.

Comment: It might be useful to look into pivot tables for grouping your data without changing the structure of the sheet.

Comment: @ClockeWork Just because of making the sheet to be familiar with some basic users

Comment: If you hide the button, I take it only you plan on expanding and collapsing the groups. As in the users will only ever see it one way, the group functionality is not for them. Is that correct?

Comment: @CLockeWork No it's not correct. I want the controller on the left goes off

Comment: So you want them to be able to expand and collapse the group, without having the buttons that they need to be able to do so?

Comment: No it is not what I want CLockeWork. I want two mode 1) `With Grouping feature` **display mode** that has the controller on the left and 2) `Without-grouping feature` **display mode** where the sheet normally as there is no grouping at all.